# Matrix size-incompatible for MNIST Fashion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm planning to migrate my Keras code from a sample script to serving mode.
I keep getting:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [128,784], In[1]: [16,16]
     [[Node: dense/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](flatten/Reshape, dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp)]]
```

Complete [log](https://pastebin.com/raw/ua7995G4)

My test images:

```
print(np.array(test_images).shape)
print(np.array(test_labels).shape)

(10000, 28, 28)
(10000,)
```

Matrix multiplication should be `mxn X nxp` to be valid, in this case input of image is 28x28 and in the model is being flatten using the Flatten layer then converted to 784, not sure what may be the issue here and how to solve it?.

Original code (Works):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (
test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)    
predictions = model.predict(test_images)
print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))
print(test_labels[0])
```

New code (Does not work):

```
def keras_estimator(model_dir, config, learning_rate):  
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

    # Compile model with learning parameters.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
        keras_model=model, model_dir=model_dir, config=config)
    return estimator


def input_fn(x, y, batch_size, mode):  
    # Default settings for training
    num_epochs = None
    shuffle = True

    # Override if this is eval
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        num_epochs = 1
        shuffle = False

    y = np.asarray(y).astype('float32').reshape((-1, 1))
    return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x,
        y=y,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        queue_capacity=50000)


def serving_input_fn():   
    feature_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    features = feature_placeholder
    return tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver(features,
                                                          feature_placeholder)

def train_and_evaluate(output_dir, hparams):    
    # Load data.
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = \
        utils.prepare_data(train_file=hparams['train_file'],
                           train_labels_file=hparams['train_labels_file'],
                           test_file=hparams['test_file'],
                           test_labels_file=hparams['test_labels_file'])

    #Scale values to a range of 0 to 1.
    train_images = train_images / 255.0
    test_images = test_images / 255.0

    # Create estimator.
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=500)
    estimator = keras_estimator(model_dir=output_dir,
                                config=run_config,
                                learning_rate=hparams['learning_rate'])
    train_steps = hparams['num_epochs'] * len(train_images) / hparams[
        'batch_size']
    # Create TrainSpec.
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
        input_fn=input_fn(
            train_images,
            train_labels,
            hparams['batch_size'],
            mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
        max_steps=train_steps)

    # Create EvalSpec.
    exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', serving_input_fn)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn=input_fn(
            test_images,
            test_labels,
            hparams['batch_size'],
            mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL),
        steps=None,
        exporters=exporter,
        start_delay_secs=10,
        throttle_secs=10)

    # Start training
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I tried flatten before and change then first input layer, same results:

```
    # flatten 28*28 images to a 784 vector for each image
    num_pixels = train_images.shape[1] * train_images.shape[2]

    train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
    test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
```

Model change:

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(784, input_dim=784, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

Comment: excuse me did you solve it ?